# получения токена и сохранения в androide

Tags: android-studio, firebase

Нужен способ, которым можно нормально хранить токены в приложении.
Есть приложение клиент, которое принимает логин-пароль и отправляет его на сервер.
Сервер сверяет данные и выдаёт приложению токен.
Однако, токен надо как-то хранить, чтобы потом по нему инициализировать пользователя.
Вопрос, как это сделать? Shared Preferences? Безопасно ли?
Нужно просто куда-то засунуть уже готовый токен и потом его достать при необходимости.